# svg not showing on my wordpress https site

Tags: wordpress, ssl, svg, https

On my website, there is a preview section which displays SVG images, however that seems to not working working after SSL install.

http://fingerprinttreegenerator.com/fingerprint-tree-generator/

https://fingerprinttreegenerator.com/fingerprint-tree-generator/

out of above 2 links - SSL doesnt showup Preview images, but normal http does.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

the above appearing in your https:// console, please double check you are calling functions properly